# Always i have to manually deactivate and activate feature manually?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, feature, feature-activation

I have a feature scoped to web. Every time i deploy my wsp using visual studio i have to manually go to the site feature and deactive and active feature to see my latest changes. Is there any setting i am missing to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio to deploy the solution check the Project property `Active Deployment Configuration`. It should be set to `Default`.
Also verify that `Site URL` property is matching your web url.

If you really want to speed up your development process you can always use some 3rd party tool like [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic settings for this. Your easiest option is to use PowerShell script.

I normally use PowerShell script, then using Visual Studio -> Package WSP. Switch Window and Run the script which

1. Retracts & Remove Solution
2. Install new Solution file (from the bin\debug folder)
3. Activate feature